# Is SmartCard-HSM 4K good enough for WebTrust level Certificate Authority ROOT KEY storage?

Tags: certificate-authority

Is **SmartCard-HSM 4K USB token** good enough for a WebTrust category CA's ROOT KEY storage or is a **FIPS 140-2 level 3** certified device required?

Are there any **FIPS 140-2 level 3** certified USB token with N-of-M management scheme and backup functionality available?

The idea is not to spend tens of thousands of dollars when not really necessary.

The intermediate certificate authorities will be handled by a **FIPS 140-2 Level 3 PCI HSM** card.

ROOT CA could also be handled by the same card in a separate slot, just thought that it would safer to have it 100% off-line.